# Calculator border does not feel right

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am building a calculator app using HTML,CSS,JS but I am stuck on a issue.

One of the button in first and last row needs to be twice the size of other buttons.

But something doesn't feel right.

Because if I try to check the border of every button should lie in a straight line.

border-right of btn "C" and "0" doesn't feel right.

I have already searched google and tried various things but I am still not getting through it.

Please try to answer it using

> flex:value;

cause I am using that.

[code on codepen](https://codepen.io/darshansharma/pen/eYMKvNK)

Ouput - [image]

HTML File:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "sourcesans";
}

.calculator {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

#textbox {
  flex: 4;
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#textbox>#tagone {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

#buttondivision {
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 4;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.calc-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 25%;
}

#clearbutton,
#zerobutton {
  flex: 2;
}

.calc-row>button {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgb(199, 255, 192);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 30px;
}

.calc-row>button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(199, 255, 141);
}

.calc-row>button:nth-child(4n+1) {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.calc-row:nth-child(1) {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div id="textbox">
    <span type="text" id="tagone"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="buttondivision">
    <div class="calc-row">
      <button id="clearbutton" onclick="clearfun()"> C</button>
      <button id="percentbutton" onclick="percentfun()">%</button>
      <button onclick="dividefun()"> /</button>
    </div>
    <div class="calc-row">
      <button onclick="setvalue('7')"> 7 </button>
      <button onclick="setvalue('8')"> 8 </button>
      <button onclick="setvalue('9')"> 9</button>
      <button onclick="multiplyfun()"> * </button>
    </div>
    <div class="calc-row">
      <button onclick="setvalue('4')"> 4</button>
      <button onclick=" setvalue('5')"> 5 </button>
      <button onclick="setvalue('6')"> 6</button>
      <button onclick="minusfun()"> - </button>
    </div>
    <div class="calc-row">
      <button onclick="setvalue('1')"> 1 </button>
      <button onclick="setvalue('2')"> 2 </button>
      <button onclick="setvalue('3')"> 3</button>
      <button onclick="plusfun()"> + </button>
    </div>
    <div class="calc-row">
      <button id="zerobutton" onclick="setvalue('0')"> 0 </button>
      <button id="dotbutton" onclick="dotfun()"> .</button>
      <button onclick="equalfun()"> = </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please adjust the value of flex acccording to your button alignment

I have updated the css in your code pane and I see the alignment in correct positions with "C" and "0" buttom.

try finding this css block in you code and replace from flex:2 to flex:2.01.

As you need the solution with flex.

```
#clearbutton, #zerobutton {
    flex: 2.01;
}
```

Comment: Why 2.01? I am giving flex:1 to all the buttons. So it should be flex:2 to the buttons which I need double the size of other btn.

Comment: This is happening because of the border size of 2 butons vs border of one button. "C" and 0 button has 4 borders and in between buttons has 7 borders combines and sharing one vertical border in between which shifts the buuton by 0.1 ,

Comment: Still not getting it. Every button has border of 1px on every edge. How does that interfere with width?

Comment: with the help of flex I have answer the question explaining the same , Please eccept the answer if it really works for you in this case. thank you,

Comment: you are unable to explain why it works? I will accept if you tell that

Comment: anyways maybe the solution will help some else in future , I think I have explained enough thank you